# How to make Dynamic Page Template based on Post ID's

Tags: page-template, id

I am trying to make download page with download link defined in posts custom field.

I want download pages to look like

> /download?p=id

I found many sites using this kind of download links. Is there actually a simple solution for this? A plugin for instance? From my understanding i would have to make page template where i set up page as i want and as for the part i want to change based on post id i pull it out of custom field. Then making shortcode to insert download page link in posts.

**EDIT** 
Based on [Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/281646/119931) answer i managed to make some progress.

1.Allowing endpoints such as ?id=

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'id', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
```

2.Pulling out custom field from post based on permalink id.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($_GET['id'], 'link', true); ?>
```

Now i have to figure out how to make posts shortlinks not easy to guess one 
by one and make shortcode. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way to append something to the end of URLs and process it in WP are [rewrite endpoints](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

It makes it easy to target specific kind of URLs and *generally* it is unlikely to explode everything, like many of rewrite modifications do.

Comment: Thanks that put me on right track. Do you perhaps know how to make shortlinks (post id) a bit more complicated, so it cannot be guessed?

Comment: I know there are libraries that allow you to generate reversible non-guessable identifiers from numeric IDs, but I don't remember any specific ones on top of my head.